# Data type in Spark is not right

Tags: apache-spark

When I create a data frame in spark, the columns are of the wrong type. I have hundreds of columns and don't know how to best change the data type of each column. Fortunately most of are supposed to be numeric.

Here is what I do:

```
val df = sc.textFile("user/name/testC.tsv")
# Removing the first line.
val dfLines = df.filter(x => !x.contains("test_name")
# I am picking columns I want.
val rowRDD = df.lines.map( x => x.split("\t")).map (x(2), x(4), x(11), x(12)))
# Creating a data frame.
val df = rowRDD.toDF("cycle", "dut", "metric1", "metric2")
```

The columns are supposed to be numeric, but `df` has only strings:

```
(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String) =
  (100,0,255,34,33,25,29,32,26,44,31,0,UP)
```

Comment: Can you show the data, so we can find out the problem?

Comment: here is what I do:

Comment: here is what I do: 
val df = sc.textFile("user/name/testC.tsv")
val dfLines = df.filter(x => !x.contains("test_name") # removing the first line
val rowRDD = df.Lines.map( x => x.split("\t")).map (x(2), x(4), x(11), x(12))) # I am picking columns I want.
val df = rowRDD.toDF("cycle", "dut", "metric1", "metric2") # creating a data frame.
the columns are supposed to be numeric, but df has only strings:
(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String) = (100,0,255,34,33,25,29,32,26,44,31,0,UP)

Answer (score 2):

When you pick the columns, you can perform conversions. For example:

```
val rowRDD = df.lines
  .map(x => x.split("\t"))
  .map((x(2).toInt, x(4), x(11).toDouble, x(12).toDouble))
```

(Assuming `cycle` is an integer, `dut` is a string, and `metric1` and `metric2` are real numbers.)

Comment: This is the best you can do. When you load the data from file everything is a String. You need to give types to your data before you convert them to DF. Otherwise you can use e.g., `dff.getAs[Int]("name")` each time you read a field.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel! This worked :)
One more if I may: how do I stack columns in a dataframe in spark while keeping other non-stacked columns in the new data frame. In R this is easily done using reshape package.

Comment: What does stacking mean?

Comment: concatenating columns on top of one another.

Comment: I don't know what concatenating columns on top of one another means either :). I don't know. If it's unrelated to this question, it's best if you ask it in a separate question. You have much better chances of getting an answer. If it _is_ closely related to this question, perhaps edit the question and describe the stacking part as well.

Comment: let's say I have the dataframe:
cycle x1 x2
1 2 6
2 4 7
3 5 9

I want to turn this table to the following dataframe:
cycle metric value
1 x1 2
2 x1 4
3 x1 5
1 x2 6
2 x2 7
3 x2 9

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Best ask a separate question I think. It's impossible to tell what you're looking for without proper formatting.

Comment: I have a csv file with 45 columns and over 500K rows. I load the csv file as RDD. But then I want to remove the last 20 columns. Since RDD is no longer a dataframe or matrix, I am not sure how to do this. Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Idea: Ask a separate question for separate problems.